# OVER and partition with multiple columns without resetting the total

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sum, window-functions

I would like to not reset a running total using the OVER clause in SQL server. I have tried several things and searched for an answer very hard, but could not find anything. My query is below, as well as the results.

```
SELECT 
    coaID,
    fiscalID,
    gl.amount,
    SUM(gl.amount) OVER (PARTITION BY coaID, fiscalID ORDER BY gl.id) runningTotal
FROM 
    gl
    INNER JOIN dbo.coa ON dbo.gl.coaId = coa.ID
WHERE 
    gl.coaID IN (
        SELECT DISTINCT coa 
        FROM glCategoryGLAccountLink 
        WHERE glCategoryGLAccountLink.categoryId = 10001
    ) 
    AND gl.companyID=1
ORDER BY coaID, fiscalID
```

It mostly works, but resets the running total when fiscalID changes. My objective is to allow the running total to continue without being reset for each coaID.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My objective is to allow the running total to continue without being reset for each `coaID`.

Remove the `fiscalID` from the partition, ie change this:

```
SUM(gl.amount) OVER (PARTITION BY coaID, fiscalID ORDER BY gl.id) runningTotal
```

To:

```
SUM(gl.amount) OVER (PARTITION BY coaID ORDER BY gl.id) runningTotal
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you still need to take `fiscalid` into account for the ordering.  So:

```
SELECT coaID, fiscalID, gl.amount,
       SUM(gl.amount) OVER (PARTITION BY coaID ORDER BY fiscalID, gl.id) runningTotal
FROM gl JOIN
     dbo.coa c
     ON gl.coaId = c.ID
WHERE gl.coaID IN (SELECT gal.coa 
                   FROM glCategoryGLAccountLink  gal
                   WHERE gal.categoryId = 10001
                  ) AND
      gl.companyID = 1
ORDER BY coaID, fiscalID;
```

It is possible that `gl.id` takes this into account.  Your question is not clear on that.

Notes:

- Qualify all column references with the table they come from.  I would have added the qualifiers, but it is not clear which table they come from.
- Table aliases help.
- `SELECT DISTINCT` is not needed with `IN`.  Most databases will ignore it, but you run the risk of the `DISTINCT` affecting the optimizer.

Comment: Your answer was helpful, and was also used in the solution, specifically the DISTINCT and aliases